# Sorting on the basis of Hash value while not overlooking the Keys

Tags: ruby

I have an array like :

```
'cars', 'for', 'racs', 'creams', 'scream'.
```

Now, what i do is that that i sort each word/string in this array and put that sorted string as a Value in a Hash while the original String is the Key. So now i have

```
KEYS - VALUES

cars - acrs
for - for
racs - acrs
creams - acemrs
scream - acemrs
```

Code for this is

```
sorted_words = Hash.new(0)
words.each { |word| sorted_words[word]=word.chars.sort { |a, b| a.casecmp(b) }.join
}
```

After this i sort Hash on the basis of value by

```
sorted_words = sorted_words.sort{|a1,a2| a1[1]<=>a2[1]}
```

and acheive

```
scream - acemrs
creams - acemrs
racs - acrs
cars - acrs
for - for
```

Instead of this i am looking for the Hash to be arranged like

```
cars - acrs
racs - acrs
creams - acemrs
scream - acemrs
for - for
```

So, in the above list the values are in sorted position as in the list i am getting now but it also considers the Key value so thats why first is car and then all other keys with the same value and the cream and then for

Comment: 'acemrs' is < 'acrs', why should those two follow the first two in your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to sort on value major order with the keys breaking the tie.  Try it like this:

```
sorted_words = sorted_words.sort{|(k1,v1),(k2,v2)| vcmp = v1<=>v2; vcmp!=0 ? vcmp : k1<=>k2 }
# => [["creams", "acemrs"], ["scream", "acemrs"], ["cars", "acrs"], ["racs", "acrs"], ["for", "for"]]
```

Comment: @JoshVoigts there is nothing obfuscated in my snippet. This is ordinary ruby used in its ordinary way. #sort, the yielding of hash members as key,value pairs, the use of the comparison operator <=>, and a ternary to chain to a secondary evaluation are quite prosaic and used as one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash[
  array
  .map{|w| [w, w.chars.sort_by(&:downcase).join]}
  .sort_by{|k, v| [v, k]}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

arr=['cars', 'for', 'racs', 'creams', 'scream']

sw=Hash.new

mm=arr.each{|word|sw[word]=word.split(//).sort{|a,b|a.casecmp(b)}.join}

ss=sw.sort_by{|key,value|[value[-1]]}.reverse

# [["cars", "acrs"], ["racs", "acrs"], ["scream", "acemrs"], ["creams", "acemrs"], ["for", "for"]]